# pandas set_index column created in Table, however column empty (value not found in row)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```py
# import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql

sql_engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:password@host?port/database',
                            connect_args=dict(user='csjowner',
                                              password='csjowner',
                                              host='localhost',
                                              port=3306,
                                              database='csj'),
                            pool_recycle=3600)

conn2 = sql_engine.connect()
  
pd.set_option('max_columns', None)
pd.options.display.width = 0

df1 = pd.read_sql_query("select shipment_num, 
commit_status,cgo_cutoff_iodt,cgo_avail_iodt,f_load_iodt,l_dsch_iodt,qty "
                        "  from cs_ship1 ")
            "order by shipment_num",
            conn2)
df2 = pd.read_sql_query("select shipment_num, commit_status, 
cgo_cutoff_iodt,cgo_avail_iodt,f_load_iodt,l_dsch_iodt,qty "
              "  from cs_ship2 ")
            "order by shipment_num",conn2)
df_all=df2.compare(df1).set_index(['shipment_num'])
#df_all.set_index(['shipment_num'])
print(df_all)

df_all.to_sql(con=conn2, name='dfx_test_table', if_exists='replace', 
index=True,index_label='shipment_num' )

conn2.close()
```

`df_all.print` does not have set_index value (shipment_num). Only index is included:

```
qty      
    self other
11   3.0   6.0
```

Process finished with exit code 0.

Table `dfx_test_table` has column `shipment_num`, and it is `NULL`. Why is it `NULL`?

```
shipment_num      qty,self    qty,other
  <NULL>                 3            6
```

Comment: If I do df_all.to_csv, shipment_num is populated correctly.   qty qty           
 self other        
shipment_num       
TST_SHPT_2 3.0 6.0

Comment: Do not know why shipment_num column value is missing when to_sql is used.  shipment_num is found to be <NULL>.